# Why would a UIScrollView bump when scrolled

Tags: uiscrollview, autolayout

Strange behavior that I can't track down.  I have a dynamic scroll view, but when scrolling it 'bumps' down just after the scroll starts and bumps back up just after.

In this example the red border is the scroll view and the green border is the content inside.  When I scroll it drops down into proper place, but then clicks up.  It just bumps down, no animation.  (The image is a gif in case your not seeing it animate)

Thanks in advance for any ideas!

[image]